# Question regarding incrementing a string value in a text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Just beginning with Powershell.  I have a text file that contains the string "CloseYear/2019" and looking for a way to increment the "2019" to "2020".  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Use `Get-Content` to retrieve the content of the file, the `-replace` operator to replace the string `CloseYear/2019` with `CloseYear/2020`, and pipe to `Out-File` to create a new text file with the string replaced in it.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to update text within a file, you can do the following, which will replace specified text with more specified text. The file (`t.txt`) is read with `Get-Content`, the targeted text is updated with the String class `Replace` method, and the file is rewritten using `Set-Content`.

```
(Get-Content t.txt).Replace('CloseYear/2019','CloseYear/2020') | Set-Content t.txt
```

---

**Additional Considerations:**

General incrementing would require a object type that supports incrementing. You can isolate the numeric data using `-split`, increment it, and create a new, joined string. This solution assumes working with 32-bit integers but can be updated to other numeric types.

```
$str = 'CloseYear/2019'

-join ($str -split "(\d+)" | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -as [int]) {
        [int]$_ + 1
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
})
```

Putting it all together, the following would result in incrementing all complete numbers (123 as opposed to 1 and 2 and 3 individually) in a text file. Again, this can be tailored to target more specific numbers.

```
$contents = Get-Content t.txt -Raw     # Raw to prevent an array output

-join ($contents -split "(\d+)" | Foreach-Object {
    if ($_ -as [int]) {
        [int]$_ + 1
    }
    else {
        $_
    }
}) | Set-Content t.txt
```

---

**Explanation:**

`-split` uses regex matching to split on the matched result resulting in an array. By default, `-split` removes the matched text. Creating a capture group using `()`, ensures the matched text displays as is and is not removed. `\d+` is a regex mechanism matching a digit (`\d`) one or more (`+`) successive times.

Using the `-as` operator, we can test that each item in the split array can be cast to `[int]`. If successful, the `if` statement will evaluate to `true`, the text will be cast to `[int]`, and the integer will be incremented by `1`. If the `-as` operator is not successful, the pipeline object will remain as a string and just be output.

The `-join` operator just joins the resulting array (from the `Foreach-Object`) into a single string.

Answer (score 0):

AdminOfThings' answer is very detailed and the correct answer.

I wanted to provide another answer for options.

Depending on what your end goal is, you might need to convert the date to a `datetime` object for future use.

Example:

```
$yearString = 'CloseYear/2019'
#convert to datetime
[datetime]$dateConvert = [datetime]::new((($yearString -split "/")[-1]),1,1)
#add year
$yearAdded = $dateConvert.AddYears(1)
#if you want to display "CloseYear" with the new date and write-host
$out = "CloseYear/{0}" -f $yearAdded.Year
Write-Host $out
```

This approach would allow you to use `$dateConvert` and `$yearAdded` as a `datetime` allowing you to accurately manipulate dates and cultures, for example.